# Crystal reports - Get page number for group failed error

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report in VS2010. It works fine in localhost and server-PC without any problem. But when I access the crystal report through any other client system the crystal report is rendered with all data and after few seconds I'm getting an error saying:

Error in File Payslip 40592_42788_{9FE88EE8-4119-40D9-8541-7211A3AD8B15}.rpt:
Get page number for group failed.

I searched the temp folder(both AppLocal and c:/windows/temp) of the server-PC but I didn't  find any file with the above name.

Note:

1. Before the crystal report rendered a blank page which has fixed by copying the  '\crystalreportviewer13' folder into my Web application and added  in web.config
2. Permissions have been given to the temp folder.
3. Page Number component is not used in my Crystal report.
4. No errors in conditions set in crystal reports as I can access the groups and even download the pdf file in that few seconds.

Here my code:

XYZ.aspx: Based on conditions data will be loaded from database to dataset and redirected to Report.aspx page.

XYZ.aspx.cs:

```
Session["printreport"] = ds;// where ds is my dataset
StringBuilder str3 = new StringBuilder();
str3.Append("<script = language='javascript'>");
str3.Append("window.open('Report.aspx?title=PayslipReport')");
str3.Append("</script>");                        
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "GenerateReport", str3.ToString()); //redirecting to report.aspx
```

Report.aspx:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" ToolPanelView="None" EnableDrillDown="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" HasDrillUpButton="False" />
```

Report.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string report = Request.QueryString["title"].ToString();
        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();

        DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["printreport"];
        if (report == "PayslipReport")
        {
            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Payslipreports.rpt"));            
        }
        rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
 }
```

Please Help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True"` in your Report.aspx (where you put the CrystalReportViewer). Also try enclosing all the `page_load` events in `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: thanks for replying but it's not working. getting the same error.

Comment: If you swap out the report for another, does it work? I think the error is suggesting some sort of problem with the report, although I have no idea what that might be. Code all looks ok to me.

Comment: Actually i just noticed you have `AutoDataBind="True"` in your viewer. Try setting this to false.

Comment: I Designed the report again and even set AutoDataBind="false" but no use.

Comment: What I observed for now is when I run the application on the server itself the crystal reports temp files are created everytime I navigate to any group in grouptree or view the next page for every request, but it is creating temp file only once on my first request on any client other than server.

Comment: Not sure what is causing it unfortunately. Sorry. The only other thing worth checking is that you have the Crystal .NET libraries (there are more than one to use) installed correctly on the server as it can be very picky about that!